# capture only 360º from velodyne HDL32E

Tags: velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've followed the tutorial [Getting Started with the Velodyne HDL-32E] and I can get a video in real time from velodyne doing:

> 1. sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.3.100 <-- IP for my PC
> 2. sudo route add 192.168.18.108 eth0   <-- velodyne IP
> 3. roslaunch velodyne_pointcloud 32e_points.launch
>    calibration:=/home/vic/32db.yaml
> 4. rosrun rviz rviz -f velodyne >  configure as the tutorial said.

It works fine, but I need to process the data from a static 360º scene, not from the video.
So I need a program which do:

1. capture a 360º from velodyne
2. process the data
3. again capture a new 360º scene

Which ROS command should I use?
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/129841/capture-only-360%C2%BA-from-velodyne-hdl32e/) by [marilia15](https://answers.ros.org/users/5506/marilia15/) on ROS Answers with karma: 104 on 2014-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Each message in the /velodyne_points topic contains all the data from a complete revolution of the device.

If you write a ROS node that subscribes to that topic, your subscription callback will be called each time a new message arrives. That happens at 10 Hz with the device spinning at the default 600 RPM rate.

Here is an [example node that reads the point cloud](https://github.com/jack-oquin/velodyne_height_map/blob/master/src/heightmap.cpp#L188) for each revolution, looking for points within some grid cells that significantly differ in the Z axis.

You can figure out from that how to write your own subscriber node.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2014-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1